# Can I add an icon & function to the "Upload/Insert" toolbar at the top of the content editor?

Tags: theme-development, uploads

Is there a built-in filter to add a custom icon and function to the WordPress "Uploads/Insert" toolbar? This is the toolbar that's located just above the content editor. The existing icon I want to replicate is shown in the blue circle of the image below.

I'd like to add a custom icon that loads the "Add an Image" wizard and passes a special parameter to the upload function such that the attached images get a special meta attribute they would not ordinarily get when uploaded via the standard icon.

[image: The editor toolbar showing the location of the menu I'm interested in adding to]

Update: With the help of tnorthcutt's answer below, I've managed to hook into the media icon filter. From here, I should be able to attach a jQuery click event to the image or href and trigger the opening of the media-upload.php, passing a parameter to process the uploads as special...

```
//Upload custom images
function addMediaIcon($initcontext)
{
    return $initcontext.
   ' <a id="myID" 
      href="javascript:;" 
      onmousedown="return false;" 
      onclick="return false;" 
      title="tooltip">
     <img 
      src="wp-admin/images/media-button-image.gif" 
      onclick="javascript:alert()" title="" />
    </a>';
}
add_filter('media_buttons_context', 'addMediaIcon');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inclined to say that this is possible. For instance, the Gravity Forms plugin adds an image here. Start with looking at the [media_buttons_context](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/media_buttons_context?version=3.0&file=wp-admin/includes/media.php) hook.

Comment: yep, that's the one. I'm looking at a few examples now > http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-uploadinsert-media-toolbar-for-posts-amp-pages

Comment: It's definately possible, the polls plugin on wordpress.com blogs does just that...of course i can't speak of implementation right now, but it's definately possible is all i'm saying..... ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can also find a good example of using the `media_buttons_context` filter on the following page.
http://www.morgadinho.org/2009/10/16/wordpress-media-buttons/

I know this probably covers what you have already, but wanted to share the link all the same... ;)